# Spring Basic Authentication Can't Log Out

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using simple basic Authentication using the Spring security 3.2 JAR, but for even when I clear my cookies, my Chrome still keeps me logged in. Also, the logout does not work either for me.

Please see my security-context.xml where I'm creating the authentication.

If the logout starts working for me It is good enough for me, as I do know that the browser likes to keep basic Auth until the browser is closed.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

    <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <http-basic></http-basic>
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"  invalidate-session="true"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="tehras" password="secret" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the browser after the logout. In basic authentication it stores the credentials for sending them in the header for each request to the website

Comment: yeah was wondering if there's a way to erase the header or something. To me it seems weird that spring-security comes with logout options but logout doesn't work.